# Asp.Net Core Different User Models to derive from ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

We have just started learning how to code and we are working on an Asp.Net Core 3.1 project i know its a simple problem but ive searched everywhere and haven't found a solution.

We have Admin, Client, Mentor User Models which have all the additional props we need from the user apart from the standard Email, Pass, First, Last name which come from the ApplicationUser model.

so we have something like this (you can find bellow the models):

```
AdminUserDetails   ---\
ClientUserDetails  ------ : ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
MentorUserDetails  ---/
```

At this moment, Authentication and Authorization works correctly but all users are created in AspNetUser Table in EF but we want each role (eg.Client) to be created in the Client table with all properties from ApplicationUser and IdentityUser, inherited.

First of all, i found [this link](https://forums.asp.net/t/2151331.aspx?Multiple%20Types%20of%20Users%20with%20Net%20core%20Identity) to inherit the models from ApplicationUser. Is this the proper way to do it?

Also, when a user registers with a role selected in the form we want to assign that user to the corresponding ...UserDetails model and get the Identity Id in Guid.

Here are some exmple models:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return FirstName + " " + LastName;
            }
        }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public int? PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Profile Picture")]
        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        public string? ProfilePicture { get; set; }
   }
```

```
public class AdministratorDetails : ApplicationUser
    {
        [Key]
        [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        //Προσθέτω Foreign key se ola ta details APP USER

        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    }
```

Startup:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>() //Πρόσθεσα Identity role
                .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
                })
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();


            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });

            //SendGrid Confirmation Email Sender
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);

            services.AddTransient<IProfileService, IdentityClaimsProfileService>();
            services.AddScoped<IJobCategoriesRepository, JobCategoryRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IMentorRepository, MentorRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IHrDetailsRepository, HrDetailsRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IClientRepository, ClientRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IJobListingsRepository, JobListingsRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IMentorOfferRepository, MentorOfferRepository>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }


            app.UseCors(
                options => options.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5001/")
                                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                                  .AllowAnyMethod()
            );

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });


            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseIdentityServer();

            CreateRoles(serviceProvider).Wait();
        }


        private async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            //adding custom roles
            var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
            var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            string[] roleNames = { "Admin", "HR", "Mentor", "Client" };
            IdentityResult roleResult;

            foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
            {
                //creating the roles and seeding them to the database
                var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
                if (!roleExist)
                {
                    roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
                }
            }


            //creating a super user who could maintain the web app

            var powerUser = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserEmail"],
                Email = Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserEmail"],

                FirstName = "PowerAdmin",
                LastName = "Admin",
                UserRole = "Admin",
                EmailConfirmed = true
            };


            string UserPassword = Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserPassword"];
            var _user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserEmail"]);

            if (_user == null)
            {
                var createPowerUser = await UserManager.CreateAsync(powerUser, UserPassword);
                if (createPowerUser.Succeeded)
                {
                    //here we tie the new user to the "Admin" role 
                    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(powerUser, "Admin");

                }

            }

        }

        public class IdentityClaimsProfileService : IProfileService
        {
            private readonly IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> _claimsFactory;
            private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

            public IdentityClaimsProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory)
            {
                _userManager = userManager;
                _claimsFactory = claimsFactory;
            }

            public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
            {
                var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
                var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
                var principal = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);
                var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
                var claims = principal.Claims.ToList();
                claims = claims.Where(claim => context.RequestedClaimTypes.Contains(claim.Type)).ToList();
                foreach(string role in roles)
                {
                    claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, role));
                }

                context.IssuedClaims = claims;
            }

            public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
            {
                var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
                var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub);
                context.IsActive = user != null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What you want is just table per type, the link should be fine.You could set `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` on AdministratorDetails.Id to assign the created userId to it.

Comment: @XingZou That's what i dont understand! Don't we get the Id from Identity User? Should i have 1 Id in ApplicationUser or 1id per User (administratorId)? Thank you for your help

Comment: I think both are OK and it depends on you, it is the foreign  key which is more vital.What I say above points to the  `get the Id from Identity User`.When you register a user, you will get the userId, then you create a record in `AdministratorDetails` model with that id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Xin Zou at the comments i finally realized that i had to remove the IdentityUser inheritance from my Users models and only set the foreign key at each User

```
 [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]
 public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
 public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
```

Thus creating an AspNetUser table but **also** a User table (according to it's role) with the foreign key of the AspNetUser. The only issue here is that the User tables have to have their props nullable.